# Why does my submodule fail to init on a fresh clone?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, git-submodules

I have a git repo `repoA` that is the parent repo. Within, I have a submodule `repoB` stored at the directory `repoB` within the cloned `repoA`'s directory.

Years ago, when I first started this project, I have been operating in the directory `devDir` where `repoA` is cloned to. To this day, I can push/fetch just fine within `devDir`.

Recently, I wanted to clone another version of `repoA` into `demoDir`. The clone of `repoA` into `demoDir` works just fine, and I can see all of the correct files. Great!

Now when I do a `git submodule update --init` I am hit with this error message:

```
user@devBox:~/repos/demoDir> git submodule update --init
Cloning into '/home/user/repos/demoDir/repoB'...
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: ERROR: The namespace you were looking for could not be found.

remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git/repoB' into submodule path '/home/user/repos/demoDir/repoB' failed
```

When I `cat demoDir/.gitmodules` I see

```
[submodule "repoB"]
        path = repoB
        url = ./repoB/
```

which is fine.

Then, when I `cat demoDir/.git/config` I see

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "repoB"]
        active = true
        url = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git/repoB
```

Now that last url line is worrisome to me, as that is not the correct path to clone `repoB` from ( when I go to gitlab's website and click the clone button, the url it gives me is `git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoB.git`).

When I edit `demoDir/.git/config` and change that last line to `url = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoB.git`, I can then run `git submodule update --init` and it is able to check everything out just fine.

The real kicker here, is when I `cat devDir/.git/config` I get basically the exact same output (for the submodule) as `demoDir`, except it's flipped

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "repoB"]
        url = git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoA.git/repoB
        active = true

[... a bunch of branches that I don't think matter]
```

So how in the HECK can one clone work fine, and the other not?

I've tried running a `git submodule sync` but no dice.

Things I've ruled out:

- Public key is not an issue, as I can clone `repoA` just fine.
- I have verified that the paths stated in `demoDir/.gitmodules` and `demoDir/.git/config` actually exist from within the browser on gitlab's site.
- I am the maintainter of all of these repos, so it is not an individual permissions issue,
- I am operating on a opensuse tumbleweed, so it is not an issue of Windoze path resolution (a lot of the google answer suggest this).

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De-initializing my submodules, and then re-initializing them worked. How did I do that?

De-init:
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-delete-a-git-submodule

Add:
`git submodule add git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoB.git repoB`

I then committed these changes and verified that I was able to clone fresh.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> When I cat demoDir/.gitmodules I see
>
> ```
> [submodule "repoB"]
>     path = repoB
>     url = ./repoB/
> ```
>
> which is fine.

This is the cause of the behaviour your are seeing. `url` should be `../repoB`. This is mentioned in the [`git submodule add` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt):

> (Please note that to specify a repository **foo.git** which is located right next to a superproject **bar.git**, you’ll have to use `../foo.git` instead of `./foo.git` - as one might expect when following the rules for relative URLs - because the evaluation of relative URLs in Git is identical to that of relative directories).

Note that in your case  `.git` is not necessary since it is added automatically by GitLab.

You then write:

> The real kicker here, is when I `cat devDir/.git/config` I get basically the exact same output (for the submodule)
> So how in the HECK can one clone work fine, and the other not?

You would have to check the config file *of the submodule* to check what is configured for `remote.origin.url`. That is, if you run

```
cd devDir/repoB
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

I would think you get `git@gitlab.com:groupname/repoB.git`, which would explain why it works. Once the submodule is initialized, Git only uses this value, not `submodule.repoB.url` in the superproject.

Comment: Thanks for the answer philb! I took a look at your suggestions, and even tho yes, your statement about `../repoB/` is correct (per the documentation) it did not help my problem.

My `remote.origin.url` was in fact pointing to the correct repo in my `devDir`. I ended up just de-initing my submodules, and then re-adding them with the long URL. I will add an answer and mark closed.